# Как к 7 дням недели присвоить имя?

Tags: php

Как присвоить числовое имя к 7 дням недели например  7 = 1, следующие 7 дней = 2
как пронумеровать недели в году?

шото мудрю вот так

$today = getdate();

$weekday = $today[wday]; //1-7

или
$nextWeek = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60;

пока не доходит как

Comment: вы недели в году хотите пронумеровать,  или что?

Comment: да  конструирую велосипед хочу вывести посетителей за неделю иначе никак как пронумеровать

Comment: вы из БД выводите статистику или как? если да, то это проще сделать сразу на стороне БД. приведите структуру таблицы и примерное ее содержимое

Comment: нет просто в файл уникве ип

Comment: все равно приведите лучше формат исходных данных, которые обрабатываете, и какой хотите получить результат. а то не ясно, что вообще нужно.

Comment: вот это  что записваю в файл 127.0.0.1|25|1|December|2017

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте получать текущий номер недели и вычислять другие по нему

```
<?php

$currentWeekNumber = date('W');
echo 'Week number:' . $currentWeekNumber;

?>
```

На выходе

```
Week number:52
```

Comment: спасибо наверно то что нужно